# Expanding of modal window

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an angular/bootstrap app and the modal window of an app contains small textarea which can contain a lot of text that does not fit the size of textarea (and modal).

I would like to add some kind of button to the small modal window which would open new bigger popup/modal containing nicely formatted content of text area, like 90% of the screen.

I am not asking here for the code, but more like for the way how to approach the problem. I have already tried several approaches but I got stuck always.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I would just use JavaScript to handle the click of your button to expand the modal size, by adding a class to your modal.

e.g. jQuery example:

```
$('.expand-modal').click(function() {
    $('.modal').addClass('expanded');
});
```

And then just write some CSS for `.modal.expanded` where you ensure it's 90% of the screen size or whatever you want.

You would probably want another button to minimise the modal again, in which case you just do something like `$('.modal').removeClass('expanded');`

Comment: Except this is JQuery and the question is tagged as AngularJS. :-(